# VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.AssemblyResolver exception

Tags: exception, vsphere

I am trying to connect to a VMware host/ vCenter through the vSphere Client from my local desktop and am getting an exception that reads:

An internal error occurred in the vSphere Client.
Details:The type initializer for 'VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.AssemblyResolver' threw an exception.

I have vCenter 5.1 installed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to log on using the Windows System credentials.
One day before I had to change my password.
So I unchecked the checkbox for using the system credentials and logged on with my new password.